# Motion Detector GUI

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I have been trying to make a GUI of the Motion detector app thought in Section 29 using tkinter, I want it to be like, there will be 4 diffrent buttons, 4 functioning for the diffrent frame which is Delta frame, Grayscale, colored and Threshold frame.
I have been trying this, but when i do it.

The button functions but the frame it shows is always the first frame, it doesnt update.

My code:

```
import tkinter
import cv2, time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
 
top = tkinter.Tk()
 
first_frame=None
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
 
while True:
    check, frame = video.read()
 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)
 
    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame=gray
        continue
 
    delta_frame=cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
 
    thresh_delta=cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
 
    thresh_delta=cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=2)
 
    (cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 
    for countour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(countour) < 1000:
            continue
    
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(countour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 3)    
 
    def Gray():
        cv2.imshow("Gray",gray)
    cv2.imshow("delta frame", delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold Delta Frame", thresh_delta)
    cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame)
 
    Button_Gray= tkinter.Button(top, text="Grayscale", command= Gray)
    Button_Gray.pack()
    top.mainloop()
   
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
    print(gray)
 
    if key==ord("q"):
        break
 
 
video.realease()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Would appreciate quick help!

Regards
Gaurav SINGH

Comment: `top.mainloop()` will never return, it'll run forever. that's the *cause* of your problem. besides, you shouldn't mix Tkinter and OpenCV's GUI functions. pick one GUI or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will show only the first frame because of `top.mainloop()`, you need to find a way to run that while loop separately.

This could be a solution but using threading with tkinter is sometimes a bad idea, so probably this is not the best solution:

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import threading

show_gray = False
show_colored = False
show_thresh = False
show_delta = False
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def Gray():
    global show_gray
    show_gray = not show_gray

def Colored():
    global show_colored
    show_colored = not show_colored
    
def Delta():
    global show_delta
    show_delta = not show_delta

def Threshold():
    global show_thresh
    show_thresh = not show_thresh

    
def stream_data():
    first_frame=None
    while True:
        check, frame = video.read()
     
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)
     
        if first_frame is None:
            first_frame=gray
            continue

        delta_frame=cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
     
        thresh_delta=cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
     
        thresh_delta=cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=2)
     
        (cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     
        for countour in cnts:
            if cv2.contourArea(countour) < 1000:
                continue
        
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(countour)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 3)    

        if show_gray:
            cv2.imshow("Grayscale frame", gray)
            
        if show_delta:
            cv2.imshow("delta frame", delta_frame)
            
        if show_thresh:
            cv2.imshow("Threshold Delta Frame", thresh_delta)
            
        if show_colored:
            cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame)
       
        key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        # print(gray)
     
        if key==ord("q"):
            break
        
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    exit()
    
def main():
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    Button_Gray= tkinter.Button(top, text="Grayscale", command= Gray)
    Button_Gray.pack()
    colored= tkinter.Button(top, text="Colored", command= Colored)
    colored.pack()
    delta= tkinter.Button(top, text="Delta", command= Delta)
    delta.pack()
    thresh_delta = tkinter.Button(top, text="Threshold", command= Threshold)
    thresh_delta.pack()
    threading.Thread(target = stream_data, daemon = True).start()
    top.mainloop()

main()
```

Also, you don't need to import `tkinter` twice and using the `wildcard` (*) is a bad idea.

Maybe this is what you need.

I want to mention Christoph Rackwitz's comment, mixing cv2 and tkinter GUI functions is a bad idea.

Comment: In this, i dont get the intended results, i wan it to be as
4 buttons, 
button 1 function: Show grayscale
button 2: show threshold frame
button 3: show delta frame etc, in your answer there is one button which makes color frame gray, in my code, i have 4 diffrent frame including grayscale, color, delta, threshold.